# Selenium Python script to check every button on a page - single page application in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, automated-tests

**Introduction**

I have a webpage with X elements. The webpage is built from a Javascript script. Each element changes the page to another page (although the entire website is a single page application)

For instance, if I have a page with 5 buttons and each button takes you to another 'page,' but a still single page application, and that other 'page' has a couple of buttons and sliders on that page itself

**Question**

1. Is there a way to automatically, check every element on my page (click every button and make sure every button does something) - and then if possible - check that every redirected action from the button, each button takes page to another part of the page, has a page where every button on that page works?
2. is there a way to have a python script that, using selenium, will check and make sure that all the elements on the page, and every page each element goes to, is working? Maybe a DFS/BFS or something?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called a budget.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do X..."* is not a good way to ask a question in SO. You want to write some code and post it here, indicating some specific issue with the code (what it does vs. what you were expecting it to do). Show what you've tried already.